# jboss SAR instead of /tomcat/shared (alfresco for example)

Tags: configuration, jboss, alfresco, sar

Hey all,
I'm curious if you can use a jboss SAR to hold all the xml, class files, and even lib files that, if you were using tomcat, were traditionally in the /shared/classes, shared/lib locations into a SAR.

The intent is that instead of messing around in the jboss/conf/ directory to simply deploy an 'appconfig.sar' beside your actual app.war/app.ear.

Example usecase is Alfresco shared/classes/**.*.

thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say this depends on your JBoss version and the [ClassLoadingConfiguration](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ClassLoadingConfiguration) you're using. I can work, but then it can just as easily break in the next version of JBoss. JBoss 7 is very strict for example.

In general I would not rely on the specific behavior of a specific JBoss version and package my dependencies with my application. If you want to share dependencies between several .war then consider having then all in in an .ear and the dependencies in .ear/lib.